# Couldn't read data because it is in incorrect format

Tags: ios

I have converted NSMutable data into string but I want this data into dictionary. For 8 days I've tried to solve this but I'm stuck on this.

I got the following response from the server:

> .<227b5c22 50617274c 222c5c22 436f6e73 756c7461 6e745c22 2c5c2243 6f756e73 656c5c22 2c5c2243 50415c22 2c5c224c 656e6465 725c225d 7d22>

Then I had convert this data into string using utf8 encoding like this.

```
Optional("\"{\\\"AAA\\\":[\\\"BBB\\\",\\\"CCC DDD\\\",\\\"EEE\\\",\\\"FFF \\\"GGG\\\"]}\"")
```

But after that I'm unable to convert it into dictionary.

Comment: are you using Alamofire ? or NSURLSession?

Comment: No. I am using salesforce SFRestRequest method.

Comment: Have you tried to convert received response data to JSON object.

Comment: Yes I tried. but is fails to convert in JSON.